# How to properly make a javascript function click a button once the function is executed?

Tags: javascript, html, function

I am trying to click a button that gets rid of the container that is currently open and once the function is executed it clicks the next button for you.

I have already tried document.getElementById("rnaMedium").click(); but that did not work.

```
function disableLowHigh(){
//rna low events
document.getElementById('rnaLow').disabled = true;
document.getElementById('rnaLow').style.opacity = 0.10;
//rna medium events
document.getElementById('rnaMedium').enabled = true;
document.getElementById('rnaMedium').style.opacity = 1;
document.getElementById("rnaMedium").click()

document.getElementById("divID").remove();
}
```

I just need the button to be clicked. I know there is an easier way to do this but this is the way I want to do it currently.

Comment: I suggest you checkout the javascript documentation on event handlers

Comment: What is your `rnaMedium` elements? A submit button within a form?

Comment: Calling `.click()` on a button with a registered handler should work, but really, why not just directly call the function that the `.click()` event would have called?

Comment: And, what does "did not work" mean? Did you open your console and check it for errors?

Comment: When the button is clicked the opacity is supposed to change and when I used the click function it didn't change, meaning it is not clicked

Answer (score 0):

as the given code above you did it the right way , but consider the following

1. but may be you do not have a function added for the button tag `<button id="rnaMedium" onclick="your function"></button>` ,
2. you have misspelled the button id,
3. what does  *the container that is currently open* mean ?  may by it pauses your function from completing execution.